# Question about autocompletion in Vim editor and html document

Tags: vimrc, autocompletion, filetype-html

Why does one of Vim's autocomplete functions (ctrl+n) not work in html documents, while the other (ctrl+p) still does?

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl-p` and `ctrl-n` does work in `html` documents in `VIM8`. Its probably something to do with a setting in your `vimrc` or one of the plugins.

Steps:

1. get a HTML document with: `wget http://www.lsu.edu/OCS/html-tutorials/writingHTML/tut/tut1.html`
2. load vim without plugins using `vim -u NONE`
3. open the `tut1.html` file that you just downloaded.
4. use `ctrl-p` or `ctrl-n` and you will see that it works.

To debug:

1. do a binary search: break up the number of plugins and their settings you have into 2 parts.
2. add one set back in your vimrc, and check if you can `vimrc` and default location. (if you are using `Vundle`, you can just comment out the lines in your `vimrc` to not load those plugins and their settings. If you are using Pathogen, move the 2nd set of plugins to a different location and comment out the settings corresponding to those plugins in your `vimrc`.)
3. If you can reproduce the problem, do a binary search in those plugins following steps #1,2
4. If you cant reproduce the problem in step#2, go to the next set of plugins and their associated settings and repeat step #1-3.